# Can't update table using stored procedure in Mysql -phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm using a procedure which is called from a trigger of tableA (say). In that procedure i am updating another table say tableB. But it is not working, I'm not getting any error but the tableB is not updating. Please help me to resolve this.

Trigger: for tableA BEFORE INSERT

```
BEGIN
   CALL his_arrear(new.Reg_No,new.Sub_Code);
END
```

Procedure:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE toup integer;
    select count(*) into toup from tableA where Reg_No=reg and Sub_Code=scode;
    update tableB set his_arrear=toup where regno=reg;
END
```

Actually here the procedure is executing but it is not updating the tableB.

Comment: more than 15 hours, there is still no response...  :(

Comment: I think you should call `Stored Procedure` in trigger `AFTER INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged SQL, here's how I'd do it within SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE his_arrear
    @reg VARCHAR(10),
    @scode VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @toup INTEGER;

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS @toup
    FROM tableA
    WHERE Reg_No=@reg AND Sub_Code=@scode;

    UPDATE tableB
    SET his_arrear=ISNULL(@toup,0)
    WHERE regno=@reg;
END
```

Notes:
 - I used `VARCHAR(10)` as you did not state your data types. Change it as needed.
 - You used `Reg_no` and `regno` in your commands. Are those column names correct?

Comment: The tag `SQL` is ***NOT*** about "SQL Server". SQL is just a *query language*. **SQL** does not refer to a specific DBMS product. Questions referring to the DBMS from Microsoft are tagged with `sql-server`